# Close all opened dialogs

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.0 I'm trying to close all dialogs on my app when a new Dialog is opened. For example, I have this menu:

```
<p:menuitem value="Filtrar móviles"
                onclick="filtrarMovilesDialog.show();"
                actionListener="#{filtrarMovilesController.reload}"
                update=":filtrarMovilesTable :filtrarMovilesForm" />
            <p:menuitem value="Usuarios" onclick="filtrarUsuariosDialog.show();"
                actionListener="#{filtrarUsuariosController.reload}"
                update=":filtrarUsuariosTable :filtrarUsuariosForm" />
```

As you see I have `filtrarMovilesDialog.show()` and `filtrarUsuariosDialog.show()` to show the dialogs.

I want to add the functionality that when I open a new Dialog, all other Dialogs must be closed. How to do that without knowing the dialog's variable names? This is just an example, I'll have a lot of Dialogs and having a list of Dialogs and closing them one by one would not be great.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you just make them all modal by `modal="true"`? This way the enduser can only open another dialog after explicitly closing the currently opened dialog.

Comment: That could be a solution but We don't want to do that so since we need to interact with some maps that are shown "behind" the dialogs.